# Why eval("475957E-8905") == "475957E-8905" is true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point, implicit-conversion

I made a program with nodeJs which generate code such as

```
eval("XXXXXX") == "XXXXXX"
```

It's working pretty well, but at a moment he gave me this :

```
    eval("475957E-8905") == "475957E-8905"
```

I tested it with Firebug, and the result is `true`
.But I don't really understand why.

Of course, `eval("475957E-8905")` return `0` 
but why `0 == "475957E-8905"` ?

Comment: Because both are evaluated/coerced to a number, and the number cannot be represented in Javascript, so 0 == 0 -> true Try alert(+"475957E-8905");

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two pieces to this puzzle: floating-point numbers and type-insensitive comparison using `==`.

First, `475957E-8905` evaluates as the floating point number `475957 * 10 ^ -8905`, which is incredibly small; in floating-point terms, it's the same as `0` due to the precision limitations of javascript. So, `eval("475957E-8905")` returns `0`.

Now, for the second piece of the puzzle.

The `==` means that the types don't have to match, so nodejs (like any JavaScript engine) tries to convert one of them so it can compare them.

Since `eval("475957E-8905")` returned `0`, it tries to convert `"475957E-8905"` to an integer as well. As we have seen, that is also `0`. Thus, the comparison is `0 == 0`, which is true.

Note that the same thing happens if you do `eval("3") == "3"` or `eval("3") == 3` -- in each case, the strings are converted to numbers and compared.

**Avoiding this problem**

You can force a type-sensitive comparison like this:

```
eval("475957E-8905") === "475957E-8905"
```

which returns false, because the `===` tells the javascript engine to return true only if the types and the values both match.

Comment: Not just node.js but any Javascript engine.

Comment: again, eval("3") === "3" would be false, this answer isn't what the asker is looking for. The problem is his floating point numbers.

Comment: @Xotic750 True. I clarified my answer.

Comment: @DamienBlack The problem is floating numbers *and* use of a type-insensitive comparison operator. `eval("3") == 3` would return true, while `eval("3") == "3"` would return false. So, it's not just the use of floating point numbers that causes this.

Comment: @EdCottrell eval("475957E-8905") == 475957E-8905 is also true. He is asking why. Since eval("475957E-8905") is 0.

Comment: @DamienBlack I know that and addressed it. The point, if you read my answer (or several of the other good ones here) is that floating point arithmetic and type-insensitive comparison both play a role here.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript has to convert your string, "475957E-8905", to a number in order to compare them. When it does that, it converts "475957E-8905" to 0 as well. So, 0 == 0;

As you can see:

```
"475957E-8905" == 0
```

Is true. Basically you `eval` statement "475957E-8905" into a number, and then the other "475957E-8905" is being converted to a number for comparison. In the end, the exact same conversion process has happened to both of them and they are both 0.

Answer (score 2):

use `===` to compare the type as well, for further information:

> JavaScript has both strict and
>   type-converting equality comparison.
>   For strict equality the objects being
>   compared must have the same type and:
>
> - Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of
>     characters, same length, and same
>     characters in corresponding positions.
> - Two numbers are strictly equal when they are numerically equal (have
>     the same number value). NaN is not
>     equal to anything, including NaN.
>     Positive and negative zeros are equal
>     to one another.
> - Two Boolean operands are strictly equal if both are true or
>     both are false.
> - Two objects are strictly equal if they refer to the same Object.
> - Null and Undefined types are == (but not ===). [I.e. Null==Undefined (but not Null===Undefined)]

check this documentation

Comment: that only fails because it is a string to a number. eval("3") === "3" would also fail

Comment: yeah but eval("3") === 3 would be true, the thing is user should read about how JS comparison operators work